# How do I tell Joda Time that the time I am giving it is for a specific time zone offset, even though the offset isn't given in the String?

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I am working with an API that provides me with a ModifyDate field that is being given in CST (-06:00), but when passing the string in to Joda time and setting the time zone to America/Phoenix, Joda time thinks that the date/time I gave it is in UTC time zone because there is no offset information being given by the API (the time being returned is in CST, confirmed with the developers).

Side note: I am in Arizona where we do not recognize daylight savings time, so I can't just apply a static offset of -1 hour.

Here's an example of what I'm dealing with:

**Field returned by the API:**

```
"modifyDate": "2020-02-11T12:23:39.817Z"
```

**Trying to format the date with Joda time:**

```
DateTime time1 = new DateTime("2020-02-11T12:23:39.817Z", DateTimeZone.forID("CST6CDT"));
System.out.println(time1);

DateTime time2 = new DateTime(time1, DateTimeZone.forID("America/Phoenix"));
System.out.println(time2);

System.out.println("----------------------------");

DateTime time3 = DateTime.parse("2020-02-11T12:23:39.817Z");
System.out.println(time3);
System.out.println(time3.toInstant());
System.out.println(time3.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("America/Phoenix")));
System.out.println(time3.toDateTimeISO());
System.out.println(time3.toDate());

System.out.println("--------------------------------");
```

**Output:**

```
2020-02-11T06:23:39.817-06:00
2020-02-11T05:23:39.817-07:00
----------------------------
2020-02-11T12:23:39.817Z
2020-02-11T12:23:39.817Z
2020-02-11T05:23:39.817-07:00
2020-02-11T12:23:39.817Z
Tue Feb 11 05:23:39 MST 2020
--------------------------------
```

As you can see in the first two outputs, by trying to apply the time zone for CST, the time provided is offset by -6 (to be expected if the time provided was in UTC). By setting the time zone to America/Phoenix, the offset is -7 (also to be expected). However, as I mentioned, the time that I am passing into DateTime is *not* UTC, it is CST.

How can I tell DateTime (or even some other library, for that matter) that the time being provided is in CST? Again, keeping in mind that when daylight savings time changes, the offset needs to be managed properly.

Comment: There’s something really wrong here. The `Z` at the end of that string means that the string is in UTC. So the offset *is* given in the string! So either you have misunderstood, or they are giving you erroneous data. I suggest that step one is to ensure that they send you correct data, whether that means fixing a bug on their side or adjusting your understanding and expectations.If they do (want to) send time in America/Chicago time zone, they should at least be able to *leave out* the erroneous `Z`, which will make it manageable on your side.

Comment: If the `Z` is in fact a mistake, you can change the time zone using `DateTime.withZoneRetainFields()`.

Comment: Interesting. I _thought_ that was the case with the `Z`, but I wasn't sure. Thanks for clarifying that. They certainly said that the time is being returned as CST and I confirmed that against some records that were updated by my warehouse. I guess I can do some finagling to check for the Z at the end, but I'm going to go back to them to see if they can fix the root issue. Thanks again.

Comment: BTW sending times in UTC (with `Z`) is recommended. If they send times in Central Time without offset, they will be sending ambiguous times one hour before *and* one hour after the clocks are turned back in fall.

Comment: @shmosel how would I use withZoneRetainFields() in this case? I've tried a few variations and it's way off.

Comment: @OleV.V. That makes sense.

I was able to figure out the withZoneRetainFields(). For some reason if I did new DateTime("String") then withZoneRetainFields() wasn't adjusting the offset correctly, but if I did DateTime.parse("String"), then I could use withZoneRetainFields() adjustment correctly. Odd.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the time being provided by the API was incorrectly being provided as UTC, even though the time is CST, as pointed out by OleV.V. The cleanest solution to this problem was to use DateTime.withZoneRetainFields(), as mentioned by shmosel.

For whatever reason, however, if I created the DateTime object by using the constructor, I couldn't adjust the time zone with withZoneRetainFields(), instead, I had to use DateTime.parse().

**I adjusted for the time zone being off by using the following logic:**

```
DateTime time4 = DateTime.parse("2020-02-11T12:23:39.817Z").withZoneRetainFields(DateTimeZone.forID("CST6CDT"));
System.out.println(time4);
System.out.println(time4.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("America/Phoenix")));
```

**Output (correct)**

```
2020-02-11T12:23:39.817-06:00
2020-02-11T11:23:39.817-07:00
```

Hopefully, this will help someone else if they come across the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for reporting your findings. I still think that you should go back to them to see if they can fix the root issue. If not, your solution is the right one. One detail: `CST6CDT` time zone ID is deprecated. Use either `America/Chicago` or `America/Winnipeg` for Central Time (Central Standard Time or Central Daylight Time as appropriate for the time of year).

Comment: Note that some UTC times may not be valid when converted to other time zones because of Daylight Savings.

Comment: @shmosel I would hope that at least they send times that are valid in Central Time, but yes, All The Bits should check how Joda-Time reacts if not (if they send times in the spring gap). The problem of sending ambiguous times before and after the fall overlap seems a bit worse to me.

Comment: @OleV.V. and @shmosel thank you both for your help on this. Thanks for the `CST6CDT` advice, I figured it looked weird, so I'll go with America/Chicago or US/Central looks to be its alias. I emailed the API provider and asked them to consider updating their codebase to account for that. We'll see if they do anything about it.

Comment: Good luck with that. Feel free to send them a link to your question here.